# how to split multiple msg.payloads in a function node, node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have an issue to figure out how to somehow in a httpin node (incoming multiple sensor payloads.) to split the different msg payloads into different flows to decode them.

I have one sensor working fine, but when i add a sensor, different model it comes into the same flow of course on the httpin node.

i need to switch, splite or code the flow into another flow so i can decode the value in the second flow.

---

The incoming flow from http is: and you can see that its coming 2 sensor payloads on the same node

Msg 1:

```
2018-06-28 07:48:02node: 247e95ef.12b1ca
msg.payload : Object
object
DevEUI_uplink: object
Time: "2018-06-28T07:48:03.349+02:00"
DevEUI: "A81758FFFE03465E"
FPort: "5"
FCntUp: "1601"
ADRbit: "1"
MType: "2"
FCntDn: "1118"
payload_hex: "0100ed02330400d60501070df2"
mic_hex: "9071659a"
Lrcid: "00000201"
LrrRSSI: "-98.000000"
LrrSNR: "15.000000"
SpFact: "12"
SubBand: "G2"
Channel: "LC8"
DevLrrCnt: "5"
Lrrid: "00000543"
Late: "0"
LrrLAT: "56.031479"
LrrLON: "12.704159"
Lrrs: object
CustomerID: "100007213"
CustomerData: object
ModelCfg: "0"
DevAddr: "E0155F2E"
```

Msg 2:

```
2018-06-28 07:48:45node: 247e95ef.12b1ca
msg.payload : Object
object
DevEUI_uplink: object
Time: "2018-06-28T07:48:46.963+02:00"
DevEUI: "0018B20000001319"
FPort: "1"
FCntUp: "1"
ADRbit: "1"
MType: "4"
FCntDn: "1"
payload_hex: "8e1900000ecd"
mic_hex: "5d7ba201"
Lrcid: "00000201"
LrrRSSI: "-99.000000"
LrrSNR: "12.000000"
SpFact: "12"
SubBand: "G2"
Channel: "LC4"
DevLrrCnt: "7"
Lrrid: "00000543"
Late: "0"
LrrLAT: "56.031479"
LrrLON: "12.704159"
Lrrs: object
CustomerID: "100007213"
CustomerData: object
ModelCfg: "0"
DevAddr: "E014801D"
```

My question is, how can i take the second flow initialy and send it to a second node red flow (split data)

[image]

Comment: Without an example of the data you want to split it isn't possible to give an answer.

Comment: You really need to include a LOT more information in your questions if you want us to be able to help

Comment: So the question is more can i split on the node name somehow? like nodexxx output 1 nodexx2 output 2

Comment: Please edit the question to add information

Comment: OK, i tried to share more information about my issue, i hope this is better than my previous post, due lack of knowledge :)

Comment: There still isn't enough information here to be able to help. It really is not clear what you are trying to do. It may better to try asking in the Slack or forum where people can step through what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited amount of information to work on I'll have a guess.

From what we can see in the available data in the incoming messages the only way to tell one message from another is the `msg.payload.DevAddr` property. Assuming this is unique and you know what type of sensor each device is then you can put a switch node after the HTTP-in (Also you really need to add a HTTP-Response node to your flow to end the incoming request properly).

The switch node would have 2 outputs and test the `msg.payload.DevAddr` property to determine which output to forward the message to.

[image]

You then wire the 2 different parsing flows to the appropriate switch output.

Comment: yes this was the correct answer, i solved it yesterday exactly like you described, SUPER and thank you so much /Andy